# issue designing audit table to track changes

Tags: .net, database, database-design, audit, audit-trail

I am new to database designing and I am designing a system which creates an identical audit record on every insert, update and delete.

Below is the design of **MyTable** and **MyAuditTable**

[image]

RefId1, RefId2 (both integers) in "**MyTable**" are reference keys to other tables, with enforced referential integrity.

Do I need to have RefId1, RefId2 in "**MyAuditTable**" enforce the referential integrity or have them as just integer values and not enforce the integrity?

What should be my ideal design?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no.

As you may not want to constrain an historical value.

Why do you need and Id on and audit table?

I go one step further and put Ref1Value and Ref2Value (not ID) so I can change it and record the value in history that it was at that time.

Comment: if I want to get the history of the column(s) of that individual table which has either RefId1 or RefId2, we might not be able to get it isnt that the case? or we might duplicate the data as well?

Comment: You will get back what you put in the table